# Not able to share entire screen on discord in Hyprland

Tags: discord

I am encountering an issue with Discord screen sharing on Arch Linux while using Hyprland. When attempting to share the entire screen, the other person sees only a black screen. However, when sharing a specific application, it works as expected.

I have attempted to address this problem by trying various third-party alternatives such as Webcord and Discord-ScreenAudio, but the issue persists. Any insights or solutions to resolve this screen sharing problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary solution would be to use OBS with a Virtual Camera. It seems to work without any issues for me but haven't tested heavily.

You can then select the OBS Virtual Cam in Discord and use it as you Camera-Device.

Answer (score 0):

sudo pacman -S xwaylandvideobridge

Comment: Please don't post code-only, [edit] your answer and add an explanation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).